# how to change english date according to nepali date in sql2014?

Tags: sql-server

in the below image you see that due_ndate and due_edate.many times it occurred that date due_edate is changed because of problem in database,
due_Edate means english date and due_ndate means nepali date.
how to change english date according to nepali date?

[image]

Comment: One of the fields should probably be a computed column or you should have a conversion table for the dates and have only one column in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no image, but I assume you're asking about formatting the date?

Date formats are explained [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: i get my answer and the answer was update (tablename) set (columnname 1=dbo.neptoeng(columnname2)

Comment: @Stuart ,can u please prove me this function dbo.neptoeng

Comment: @RabiKarki can u please prove me this function dbo.neptoeng